# How to sync the lines in a text box with the rows of a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a text box that contains lines of data similar to this:

```
sheep
haggis
red squirrels
chickens
rabbits
```

and a SQL CE table with one column, titled `foods`, that stores these values. What is the best way to sync these two data sources? For example, if a user deletes `red squirrels` and `chickens` from the textbox and adds `carrots`, the table rows that contains `red squirrels` and `chickens` should be deleted and a new row inserted that contains `carrots`.

Right now, my solution is to compare the old list with the new list and perform two actions. 1) Find the items that have been removed by comparing the lists using `Except`:

```
List<String> removedFoods = oldList.Except(newList).ToList();
```

These tags are removed with `DELETE`. Another `Except` statement finds the tags that have been added, which are then added with `INSERT`.

```
List<String> addedFoods = newList.Except(oldList).ToList();
```

Is their a better way that involves one C#/SQL statement that I'm missing (or a better way in general)?

Comment: How many "foods" do you have in the table? How many users use the app parallel?

Comment: Easiest, code-wise, is to just start a transaction, delete the table's contents, then re-insert whatever's inside the text box. but this could cause problems if those records are in a cascade delete/update foreign-key relationship.

Comment: Don't put them all in one text box is the better way. You could write lots of code to deal with the fact that you have, but all it would be doing is moving the problem about.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Less than 100. The app uses an embedded database, so it's just one user using the app in parallel. I was mainly asking just out of interest. I know what they say about premature optimisation, and with such few items, I'm just curious if there was a "preferred" way.

Comment: @MarcB - Unfortunately, these records are primary keys in a cascade-on-delete foreign-key relationship, so that isn't really an option.
Tony - The user wants to be able to update the list in one text box, though. What would you recommend as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about performance right? I don't see much room for improvement in performance from what you are doing already. No matter what, you have to do deletion and insertion.
As Tim asked in his reply to your question, it depends on the number of foods in your table.

You could clear the table data like following:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE foods
```

> MSDN: TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to the DELETE statement with no WHERE clause; however, TRUNCATE TABLE is faster and uses fewer system and transaction log resources

and then use the text box data to insert the correct data back in.

Comment: See my comments to the original question. These items are in a cascade-upon-delete FK relationship, so `TRUNCATE` won't work. It looks like I'll be sticking with my current solution, since this isn't a question of performance, just a question of the "preferred" way of doing this (or, if there was a simple way that I was just missing).

Comment: I updated my question a little since I'm actually using SQL Compact Edition. I didn't realise at the time that SQL CE doesn't support the `TRUNCATE` statement, so I wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to make a datagrid that looks like a multi line textbox than to do all the parsing and handling yourself.

Keeping track of the lines/rows will be much easier.

Deleting and updating too.